# Get direction vector of a line from a point and its rotation.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry

The title pretty much says what I need. Some details about my problem:

- I have a cylinder.
- I have a point outside this cylinder.
- I want to find the direction from said point to the line that passes right through 
  the middle of the cylinder. For that, I need the equation of said line.
- I only have the coordinates for the middle point of the line and it's rotation relative to the world axis.

Comment: How do you define the rotation?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: What do you mean by the direction of a point to a line?

Comment: What do you mean by mid point of the line?

Comment: @saulspatz the direction vector perpendicular to the line that goes trough my point

Comment: @LoveInvariants The coordinates of the middle of the object. Sorry, probably the fact that it's the middle doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what your description of the geometry is. I assume that you start with a cylinder at origin, pointing along say $\hat z$ axis. You then rotate the cylinder using some angles. You can write the rotation matrix $R$ using the description on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions). Then the new direction will be $R\hat z$. You now move the center of the cylinder ro a position described by vector $\vec r_0$. The parametric equation of the line going along the axis of the cylinder is $$\vec r_{axis}=\vec r_0+\lambda R\hat z$$
with $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

Now you have a point $\vec r$ somewhere in space, and you want to calculate the perpendicular from $\vec r$ to the line above. The answer can also be found [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Vector_formulation).

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain the rotation. I have an object in my game engine with a field called rotation and 3 numbers, on the xyz axis system. Here's the definition from the documentation: "The rotation of the transform in world space stored as a Quaternion."

Comment: If you have the rotation as a quaternion $q$, $R\vec z$ in the above equation needs to be replaced with $q\hat z q^{-1}$. Look up quaternions on wikipedia. Anyway, If it's in a piece of code, look up the documentation for the API for the rotation object. See if they have something like "rotateVector" function.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to do here. I'm not trying to rotate the object, I'm trying to figure out the equation for the line that goes trough the middle of the cylinder. I have the coordinates of one point on the line (the middle of the cilinder), it's rotation in regards to the xyz coordinates system, and, I've just realised, the scale of the object relative to it's centre. The latter is a vector (x, y, z) that represents the distance from the centre to one of the sides, mainly the y coordinate is the distance to the top and bottom.

Comment: (cont) Can I use this to find the world coordinates of the centre on one of the faces?

Comment: What I don't understand is what is the "rotation" you describe. You have multiple ways of describing the rotation. If you use a rotation matrix, the direction of the cylinder is $R\hat z$. If you use a quaternion, the direction of the line is $q\hat z q^{-1}$. But you **must** have some documentation (or code) to understand what definition is used. If I say the position is $(5,0,0)$, somewhere one must specify the origin, the units of measurements, and direction of the axes.

Comment: You know, I that equation might just be what I need to make it work (except I'd probably do it on the y axis). I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: I've figured it out! Whenever I change an angle in the rotation field, it applies a rotation matrix around the X, Y and Z axis (in this order) relative to the centre of the object. To find another point on the line, I just take (0, 1, 0), apply the same matrix to it, then add the coordinates of the centre in order to find the new point in relation to the world coordinates. Did I get this right?

Comment: Sounds right. Now you have the parametric equation of the line, you can figure out the rest.